# undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv' and friends - building without stdlib but with -mfloat-abi=hard

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to build a project for Cortex-M4F. The Chip has a FPU, so I'm building with `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard` and I'm not using any libraries in order to save space, so I do `-nostdlib -fno-builtin`.

Now I want to use floating point operations, but when doing so I get a linker error:

```
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0xc): undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2d'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x24): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x36): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x48): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x54): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2f'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x9e): undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2d'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0xb6): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0xc8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0xda): undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0xe6): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2f'
led1642gw_gain.c:(.text.led_calculateGain+0x10c): undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2d'
```

Why is that? If I understand correctly, it shouldn't have to rely on library functions but use ARMs native FPU instructions for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your core supports single-precision floating point instructions however your code works with double-precision floating point.

You can notice all the missing __aeabi stuff has a 'd' (as in double) mentioned.

If you have floating point literals in your code, by C standard they are considered double. You can force them into single-precision range by adding a `f` or `F` at the end of literal.

> **2.13.3 Floating literals**: The type of a ﬂoating literal is double unless explicitly specified by
>   a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float...

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that in C, floating point literals (e.g. 1.23) have type double. As a consequence, any calculation that involves them is promoted to double.

To solve this, add 'f' to the end of all literals i.e.,

```
if (x < 2.5) ...
```

to

```
if (x < 2.5f) ...
```